# Gnome/metacity and Chrome bug leading a to a falal error

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, window-manager, metacity

since today I have a very annoying bug, opening a new tab in Chrome can make my system crash and I have to reboot. When I right click with you mouse in Chrome I see a black box instead of the standard contextual menu.

[image: black box]

Also in Firefox, tabs have a weird shadow I didn't had before. (on the left)

[image]

The 2 browsers are far slower than before. I don't understand because I didn't changed any of my window manager / desktop settings recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to turn off the hardware acceleration as described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810888/right-click-shows-black-box-in-chrome-on-linux . So I guess a system update changed something in my display driver/manager so this issue happens.